# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport dynamic height

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll, angular16, ionic7

I am working on a Ionic 7 application with Angular 16. In this version of Ionic, `ion-virtual-scroll` was deprecated and they recommend to use the `@angular/cdk` ScrollingModule. [Ionic Virtual Scroll Migration](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/virtual-scroll)

The problem is the following: I have the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` inside a cupertino pane ([See Cupertino Pane NPM docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cupertino-pane)) with 3 breakpoints.

In the lower breakpoint, the virtual scroll works well, but in the other break points the container is not adapting to the pane height. (the virtual scroll background is red for this demo).

bottom breakpoint

[image]

middle breakpoint

[image]

top breakpoint

[image]

As you can see, in the middle and top breakpoint of the pane, the virtual scroll is still rendering like the initial one, this is because the rendering viewport is not adapting to the height of the pane.

This is how the console shows the virtual scroll:

[image]

How can I do to make the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` render the virtual scroll as the panel height?